# check if value in tuple of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, bigdata

I have huge a dataframe (38 milj rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'I':[1,2,3,4], 'C':[80,160,240,80],
                   'F':[(1,2,3,4),(5,7,2),(9,6,2,5,7),(4,0,8,3,2)]})

     C                F  I
0   80     (1, 2, 3, 4)  1
1  160        (5, 7, 2)  2
2  240  (9, 6, 2, 5, 7)  3
3   80  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)  4
```

Now I would like to filter out the rows which contain the number `3` in `'F'`

To give:

```
     C                F  I
0   80     (1, 2, 3, 4)  1
3   80  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)  4
```

Is there a high performant, low memory usage way to do this?

I tried `np.equal((3), df['F'].values).all()` but this obviously does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `in` with `list comprehension` if performance is important:

```
df = df[[3 in x for x in df['F']]]
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['F'].apply(set) >= set([3])]

print (df)
   I   C                F
0  1  80     (1, 2, 3, 4)
3  4  80  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)
```

Performance (depends of the number of matched values, and of the length of `df`, too):

```
#[40000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [166]: %timeit df[[3 in x for x in df['F']]]
5.57 ms ± 132 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [167]: %timeit df[df['F'].apply(lambda x: 3 in x)]
12.2 ms ± 625 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [170]:  %timeit df[df['F'].apply(set) >= set([3])]
29 ms ± 396 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [171]:  %timeit df[pd.DataFrame(df['F'].values.tolist()).eq(3).any(1)]
37.4 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Better structure, like pointed @jpp is create:

```
from itertools import chain

lens = df['F'].str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'I' : df['I'].values.repeat(lens),
    'C' : df['C'].values.repeat(lens),
    'F' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['F'].tolist()))
})
print (df)
    I    C  F
0   1   80  1
1   1   80  2
2   1   80  3
3   1   80  4
4   2  160  5
5   2  160  7
6   2  160  2
7   3  240  9
8   3  240  6
9   3  240  2
10  3  240  5
11  3  240  7
12  4   80  4
13  4   80  0
14  4   80  8
15  4   80  3
16  4   80  2
```

Comment: Thanks all, which one is the fastest? I presume `set`?

Comment: @Ward - fastest is `in` with list comprehension I think.

Comment: @Ward - added recomended structure of data - flattening tuples to column and repeat `I` and `C` columns.

Comment: The expanded dataframe is more like it. **But** the best solution depends on *how ragged* the array is... e.g. are you going to get 1 value in one tuple versus 100 in another. If you always have 3-5 values, my solution is likely better. If it's very ragged, jezrael's expanded version is better.

Comment: @jpp - yes, I agree, it depends of real data. But it not create `NaN`s - like in your solution, but it repeat rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `in` operator in combination with `apply` method by passing a `lambda` *expression*.

```
df[df['F'].apply(lambda x: 3 in x)]
```

Output

```
   I   C                F
0  1  80     (1, 2, 3, 4)
3  4  80  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a high performant, low memory usage way to do this?

**No, there isn't.** A series of tuples is not vectorised. It consists of a double layer of pointers, which is not suited to Pandas / NumPy. You can use hacks such as the `str` accessor or a list comprehension. Or, even, attempt to expand into a dataframe:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(df['F'].values.tolist()).eq(3).any(1)

print(mask)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

But all of these are expensive. To improve performance, you should look to improve how data is structured *before* the series is constructed.

Comment: I used tuples because i thought it would reduce memory usage. Actually it is a list of int's ('F'), which have a cost ('C') associated with an index ('I'). Is there a better way to structure the series for performance?

Comment: No, `tuple` does **not** reduce memory storage. NumPy arrays reduce memory storage by avoiding the use of pointers and using a contiguous memory block.

Comment: So, i should put these list of int's into a numpy array and then into the dataframe?

Comment: If you are planning to perform *multiple* calculations or store data, yes. In fact, that's what my solution does if you break it down. For a *one-off, isolated* calculation jezrael's solution is better.

Comment: No, ill need to perform multiple calculations on the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple apply inside a `loc` will do the trick

```
df.loc[df.F.apply(lambda t : 3 in t)]


    I   C   F
0   1   80  (1, 2, 3, 4)
3   4   80  (4, 0, 8, 3, 2)
```